# horizontal scrollview not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, scrollview

In my application I have to implement the functionality of the horizontal scrollview. I have written code as follows:

coding of .h file

```
UIScrollView *HorizontalScroll;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *HorizontalScroll;
```

I have set its synthesize property. coding of .m file.

```
[HorizontalScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(330,69)];
[HorizontalScroll setFrame:CGRectMake(0,126,320,69)];
```

but it is not working.

in interface builder I have joined its outlet to file's owner.

plz tell me modification or another code which helps me.

thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entire code is perfect

I just shifted the code from viewWillAppear method to viewDidload method.

and its works fine

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine for me.
Check your IBOutlet again :), also set content size and frame in **viewDidLoad** method of view controller.

Add ScrollView programmatically.
Heres code for h file

```
 UIScrollView *HorizontalScroll;
```

code for m file:(in viewDidLoad of ViewController)

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    HorizontalScroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,126,320,69)];
    [HorizontalScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(330,69)];
    [HorizontalScroll setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]]; // color is set just to know where the scroll view is , remove this line afterwards.
    [self.view addSubview:HorizontalScroll];
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HorizontalScroll.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, 550);
```

And drag it and connect to your scrollview controller in xib.